# Bedeutung von "Moderteppich"

Tags: meaning, noun

In einem Computerspiel habe ich folgenden Dialog gesehen :

> Untoter: Ein Ungläubiger im Hort des Meisters! Verdammnis über dich!
>
> Held: Verdammt sein wirst DU, stinkender Moderteppich!

(Der Dialog im Spiel: https://youtu.be/63wtgGcJkEg?t=1m10s )

Mir ist leider unklar, was das Wort "Moderteppich" meinen soll. Nach eine Suche im Internet, bin ich fast sicher, dass das Wort war besonders von der Person, die die Dialoge fürs Spiel geschrieben, erfunden (die meisten von Google Ergebnisse enthalten diesen Dialog). Aber ich glaube, dass es verständlich für ein Muttersprachler ist und ihm lustig klingt.

Das Wort ist aus zwei Teilen gebaut:

> Der Moder - Ergebnis eines Fäulnisprozesses
>
> Der Teppich - Fußbodenbelag aus Stoff
>
> (de.wiktionary.org)

Bedeutungen beider Teilen sind mich ganz klar. Der Grund der Nutzung des ersten Teils ist auch einfach: der Untoter ist eine Art von Zombie - eine Leiche die von Magie belebt wird - darum "Moder". Aber wieso hat der Autor das Word "Teppich" benutzt? Ist das nur wegen das Wort klingt hier merkwürdig und komisch? Oder gibt es etwas anderes, dass macht diese Phrase lustig?

Noch eine Frage: In Google, habe ich auch ein paar Kleinanzeigen mit Phrase "Moder-Teppich" gefunden. Sind sie nur Tippfehler, und die Autoren meinten "Modern-Teppich"?

Comment: Es ist für Muttersprachler sofort verständlich, was gemeint ist. Solche "Worterfindungungen" sind im Deutschen alltäglich. Der Autor hat sicher deshalb "Teppich" benutzt, weil sicher jeder schonmal einen modrigen Teppich gerochen hat und weiß, wie schlimm das ist. Aber eben nicht so schlimm, dass man nichts dagegen tun könnte. Wie eben auch gegen diesen (eher harmlosen) Zombie. Was die Kleinanzeigen angeht, sind das sicher Schreibfehler.

Comment: Einen "Hört des Meisters" gibt es übrigens nicht - Ich denke, das sollte "Hort" heißen

Comment: @tofro: richtig, das war mein Schreibfehler. Danke.

Comment: @Janka: danke für die Erklärung. Irgendwie, ich dachte nicht über dem Geruch eines alten, modrigen Teppich. Das bedeutet, dass es keine Hintergrundgeschichte gibt, und der Autor ebenso gut z.B. "Modergemüse" oder "Moderpilz" benutzen können hat, oder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ein *Moderteppich* ist ein Teppich, der modert, aus dem Modergeruch aufsteigt oder ähnliches. Der Wortbestandteil *moder-* ist wahrscheinlich gewählt worden, um die Verwesung eines Zombies auszudrücken.

Zusammengenommen soll *Moderteppich* natürlich eine Beleidigung sein; *Moderwichtel* hätte es auch getan oder *Modergemüse.* *Moderpilz* wäre wahrscheinlich nicht ganz so gut gewesen, denn *Pilz* als Beleidigung passt nicht wirklich zur Situation.

Mir fallen mehrere Ideen ein, warum die Übersetzer *Teppich* als Hauptwort (und nicht etwas anderes) genommen haben könnten.

- Ein Teppich liegt normalerweise nur faul auf dem Boden herum. Man könnte es als impliziertes »du faules Stück« verstehen.
- Ein Teppich wird auf den Boden gelegt, so wie der spielbare Charakter vorhat, den Zombie auf dem Boden auszulegen, wenn er mit ihm fertig ist (modern tut er ja schon).
- Auf einem Teppich wird herumgegangen, also wird er mit Füßen getreten. Auch das könnte ein Vorgriff auf das Schicksal des Zombies (liegt am Boden, kriegt einen Fuß in das Gesicht) sein.

Nichts davon ist jedoch zwingend; hätte es im Dialog *Modergemüse* geheißen, wären mir andere Erklärungen eingefallen.

---

Einen Blick auf die Google-Ergebnisse habe ich auch geworfen. Sie wirken für mich alle wie sehr schlechte Maschinenübersetzungen und oft ist noch nicht mal von einem *Moderteppich* die Rede, sondern die Wörter *Moder* und *Teppich* sind schlicht hintereinandergereiht. Darüberhinaus bekommt man auch viele Ergebnisse, die sich mit dem Suchbegriff `moder*` erklären lassen: Folgt man dem Link, findet man nur das Schlüsselwort *modern.*

Comment: Danke, diese Antwort erklärt mir viel!